Creating a hard mesh with good topology
I'm stuck trying to figure out what to do with this bunch of vertices. I was thinking about trying to make a mesh transition, but I don't really feel that it's an option here, therefore that's the only solution I'm having in mind.
What would you do? I'm trying to make this mesh and practice good practice for modeling, so feels like given up to fix it as a not cool way.

Access the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jluNda8yplkNnKP9dwh4LP9esEdecPas/view?usp=share_link

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

@moonboots Sorry, my bad. I'm trying to fill that gap that is inside the mesh. That suppose to be a cellphone screen. Those points highlighted are exemples of the vertices that are presente on the mesh and causing me problems to elaborate how to fill it properly. Cause, as you can see, there's only a 2 dots edge below.

your link asks for an authorization  ;)

@moonboots Thought was public, sorry for that, and the delay. I was very busy at the moment. Already could achieved a resolution for my problem using the tips given by Crantisz. I'm very glad about yours and all community support that has being given to me as a beginner. Thank you so much. Have a nice day.

If Crantisz' answer is correct, mark it as such   ;)

I did it like this. This won't be deformed, so good topology isn't necessary, but try not to make polygons too wide and complexly shaped N-gones - they can cause artifacts


Wow! I really liked the way you did it. I'll try something equal. Thank you.

@ramongomes This site is not a regular forum, Please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead upvote the post that helped you. If you feel it completely solved your issue consider marking it as accepted.
